# PHP DOM DOCUMENT REPLACE DIV to text, REPLACE DIV to DIV

Tags: dom, replace, document

How to replace the div in the HTML page with plain text using the dom document?
How to replace the div in the HTML page with another div using the dom document?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
$ Element = $ dom-> getElementById ('id');
$ NodeDiv = $ dom-> createElement ("div", "New content");
$nodeDiv->setAttribute("id", "newid");
$ Element-> parentNode-> replaceChild ($ nodeDiv, $ element);

$ Element = $ dom-> getElementById ('id');
$ NodeText = $ dom-> createTextNode ("New content");
$ Element-> parentNode-> replaceChild ($ nodeText, $ element);
```